# Take and save photo in MAUI Android using camera

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

In MAUI (.NET7) (only Android) I want to be able to open the camera app, take a picture, and save the picture in a location where it can be opened by the gallery. Seems simple enough, but I can't seem to get it working.

The below code opens the camera and saves the image to either AppDataDirectory or CacheDirectory (depending on which line is executed). However neither of these two directories seem to be visible for the Gallery app to see.

```
if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
{
    FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();
    if (photo != null)
    {
        //string localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
        string localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, photo.FileName);

        using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
        using FileStream localFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);
        await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);
    }
}
```

I have tried the [Media Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) Nuget. This does save the file, but save it twice for some reason, and one of the two created files is corrupted. (I think there is an issue in github for this). It is also no longer being maintained, so I would rather not use it if possible.

Does anyone know how I can do this in MAUI? Thanks.

Comment: Please mention full paths in actual storage.

Comment: Do you mean the full paths for the CacheDirectory and AppDataDirectory? I'm not sure about these, as FileSystem is a MAUI class and I don't know what it uses for the full paths.

Comment: The full paths you use of course.

Comment: The FullPath property doesn't always return the physical path to the file. To get the file, use the OpenReadAsync method.

Answer (score 2):

```
var foto = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
     if (foto != null)
     {
         var memoriaStream = await foto.OpenReadAsync();
         imgFoto.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => memoriaStream);
         string localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory,foto.FileName);
         using Stream source = await foto.OpenReadAsync();
         using FileStream localFile = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);
         await source.CopyToAsync(localFile);
         localFile.Close();
         using (var stream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
         {
             // Get the byte array of the image.
             byte[] imageBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
             stream.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
             using (var db = new DemoDbContext())
             {
                 var imageItem = new Fotos
                 {
                     Imagen = imageBytes
                 };
                 db.Fotos.Add(imageItem);
                 db.SaveChanges();
             }
         }
         await DisplayAlert("Mensaje", "Fotografia de Paciente Almacenada", "Cancelar");
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

If You are using android than don't forget to add this permissons.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
```

Here I Defined Proper File path for Save & open Images

```
string sGpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    
string localFilePath = Path.Combine(sGpath, photo.FileName);
```

And here How You Open saved image is..

```
 string ReadFilePath = Path.Combine(sGpath, photo.FileName);

 imgFoto.Source = Path.Combine(sGpath, photo.FileName);
```

Defined Image Xaml You can see here

```
 <Image 
    x:Name="imgFoto"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

Here is Complete Xaml.cs Code..

```
 if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
 {
     FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();

     if (photo != null)
     {
         string sGpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

         // save the file into local storage
         string localFilePath = Path.Combine(sGpath, photo.FileName);

         using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
         using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

         await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);

         // Open the file into local storage
         string ReadFilePath = Path.Combine(sGpath, photo.FileName);

         imgFoto.Source = Path.Combine(sGpath, photo.FileName);
     }
 }
```